# Assign category based on boolean condition

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to figure out if there's a better way to categorize data based on a condition.

***Example Data:***
Seeing if identified places have *physical*, *social*, and/or *economic* roles. If any/many of the roles are present, the place is marked with "1".

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1,1,1], [1,1,0], columns=["PHYSICAL", "SOCIAL", "ECONOMIC"])
```

*Data*

```
|   | PHYSICAL | SOCIAL | ECONOMIC | 
| - | -------- | ------ | -------- | 
| 0 | 0        | 1      | 0        | 
| 1 | 0        | 1      | 1        | 
| 2 | 0        | 1      | 0        | 
| 3 | 0        | 0      | 1        | 
| 4 | 1        | 1      | 1        |       
| 5 | 1        | 1      | 0        |
```

***What I Want to Know:*** How to make a new *column* that assigns each row a *category* based on True/False values.

All Possible Categories:

- Physical (Only)
- Social (Only)
- Economic (Only)
- Physical & Social
- Physical & Economic
- Social & Economic
- Physical, Social, & Economic (All)

*Expected Results*

```
|   | PHYSICAL | SOCIAL | ECONOMIC | CATEGORY        |
| - | -------- | ------ | -------- | --------------- |
| 0 | 0        | 1      | 0        | social          |
| 1 | 0        | 1      | 1        | social_economic |
| 2 | 0        | 1      | 0        | social          |
| 3 | 0        | 0      | 1        | economic        |
| 4 | 1        | 1      | 1        | all_cat         |
| 5 | 1        | 1      | 0        | physical_social |
```

***What I've tried:***

```
df['CATEGORY'] = np.where(df['PHYSICAL'], np.where(df['SOCIAL'], 
np.where(df['ECONOMIC'], 'All', 'FALSE'), 'FALSE'), 'FALSE')
```

Thank you!

Comment: do you have any code to review?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [df.dot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html#pandas-dataframe-dot) for that

```
df['CATEGORY'] = df.dot(df.columns + '_').str.rstrip('_').str.lower()
```

Output:

```
   PHYSICAL  SOCIAL  ECONOMIC                  CATEGORY
0         0       1         0                    social
1         0       1         1           social_economic
2         0       1         0                    social
3         0       0         1                  economic
4         1       1         1  physical_social_economic
5         1       1         0           physical_social
```

Comment: cleanest answer here

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try this solution too

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1,1,1], [1,1,0]], columns=["PHYSICAL", "SOCIAL", "ECONOMIC"])

def get_category(physical,social,economic):
    if physical ==1 and social ==1 and economic ==1:
        return 'all_cat'
    elif physical ==0 and social ==0 and economic ==0:
        return 'None'
    elif physical == 1 and social == 1 and economic == 0:
        return 'physical_social'
    elif physical == 1 and social == 0 and economic == 1:
        return 'physical_economic'
    elif physical == 0 and social == 1 and economic == 1:
        return 'social_economic'
    elif physical ==1:
        return 'physical'
    elif social == 1:
        return 'social'
    elif economic == 1:
        return 'economic'

df['category'] = df.apply(lambda x:get_category(x['PHYSICAL'],x['SOCIAL'],x['ECONOMIC']),axis=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this the desired outcome? It's quite a brute force approach if you don't mind.

```
df['CATEGORY'] = ''
for col_name in df.columns:
    df.ix[df[col_name]==1, 'CATEGORY'] = df['CATEGORY'] + '_' + col_name
df['CATEGORY'] = df['CATEGORY'].apply(lambda x: x.lower().strip('_'))
df
```

output

```
    PHYSICAL    SOCIAL  ECONOMIC    CATEGORY
0   0           1       0           social
1   0           1       1           social_economic
2   0           1       0           social
3   0           0       1           economic
4   1           1       1           physical_social_economic
5   1           1       0           physical_social
```